# Does TFS Build have something like a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkinsfile

I've seen some custom settings files used in combination with TFS build, but nothing native.  Does Team Foundation Server or Visual Studio Team Services have a Jenkinsfile-like, declarative method for defining a build process?

Comment: Do you have any specific requirements for TFS Build? That would probably help any answer to actually help you solve your problem—what I think is like a Jenkinsfile might be different to what you're expecting, so a few constraints would be useful to know.

Comment: I'm generally looking to provide the ability to source-control the build process, in the same way that a Jenkinsfile does.  TFS build pipelines are very opinionated, and fine-grained access to them doesn't look possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strict answer is no, in that there is no direct equivalent to a [`Jenkinsfile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/). However, there are [Build Process Templates](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/update-customized-process-template) and you can use the [Psake Build Automation](https://github.com/psake/psake) tool in combination with templates to reduce the barriers to entry for creating a new build, test and deployment build definitions.

It is nowhere near as fluid as [Jenkins' Pipelines as Code](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/), [AppVeyor's `appveyor.yml`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=appveyor.yml&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB714GB714&oq=appveyor.yml&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2689j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), [CircleCI's `circleci.yml`](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/) and [Travis' `.travis.yml`](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/).  There is a wealth of information on the [ALM Rangers Library of tooling and guidance solutions.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2015/04/22/library-of-tooling-and-guidance-solutions-aka-msvsarsolutions/)

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio Team Services has a [YAML Build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/build-yaml) feature in public preview that allows you to store your build definitions as source controlled files.